# How to publish messages from a room with reactive programming?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I deal with the topic of reactive programming.
I use WebFlux and R2dbc to access the database.
I am developing a small backend for a chat app.
So I have some questions on the subject and I would be very happy about suggestions and improvements.

This is service class

```
@Service
public class MessageService implements IMessageService {

    UnicastProcessor<Message> hotProcessor = UnicastProcessor.create();
    private final FluxSink<Message> fluxSink = hotProcessor.sink(FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.LATEST);
    private final Flux<Message> hotFlux = hotProcessor.publish().autoConnect();



    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public Flux<Message> findAll() {
        return this.messageRepository.findAll();
    }


    public Mono<Message> create(Message nachricht) {
        this.fluxSink.next(nachricht);
        return this.messageRepository.save(nachricht);
    }

    // how can I persist messages and to arrange a chat room.
    public Flux<Message> finAllMessagesByChatroomId(Long id) {
        return hotFlux.filter(m->m.getId().intValue() == id.intValue());        
    }
}
```

When should I use UnicastProcessor when DirectProcessor.

**Update:** 
a little correction

```
public Flux<Message> finAllMessagesByChatroomId(Long id) {
        return hotFlux.filter(m->m.getRoom_id == id);        
}
```

But how can I get all the Messages from the database and add it to fluxSink?

Comment: I see three different questions in the body and the title of your text. Please clarify which you want to be answered and what the exact problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to save data in database and if anyone is in the chat room, then he should get messages.
I'm very unsure what to do exactly.